# How to get the DPI of the display screen in Qt

Tags: qt

I need to get the DPI value of display in Qt. I am able to get it in Qt 5.0 using the following:

```
#include <QScreen>

......
......
QScreen *srn = QApplication::screens().at(0);
qreal dotsPerInch = (qreal)srn->logicalDotsPerInch();
```

But the same code throws a compilation error in Qt version  4.x. My project is developed in Qt version 4.x. So I need the equivalent of the above code in Qt version 4.x.

Answer (score 3):

In Qt 4.8 this seem to do the trick:

```
#include <QDesktopWidget>

...
int dpiX = qApp->desktop()->logicalDpiX();
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of getting information in Qt5:
QWidget contain physicalDpiX, physicalDpiY, logicalDpiY et cetera...
(QWidget inherit them from QPaintDevice.)
(thought the OP said Qt4, but Qt5 is in development currently.)

---

Story:
I was facing the same issue.
After @code_fodder answer (though in-complete but still deserve credit).
mentioned of QPaintDevice contain those relevant methods.

after reading more over, in noticed,
QWidget inherits QObject and **QPaintDevice** and when i saw, that was it!.

Comment: That returns display metrics for the display any given widget is currently rendered to. The question is asking for display metrics of a **specific** display. This answer does not address that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a Qt5 addition. For Qt4 or older (I think its supported in 3... but can't remember) you can use the `QPaintDevice` to get similar information.
Here are the functions that will be useful to you depending what you need to do:

```
#include <QPaintDevice>
...

QPaintDevice paint;
int dpiX = paint.logicalDpiX();
int dpiY = paint.logicalDpiY();
int width = paint.widthMM();
int height = paint.heightMM();
```

**Note:** This is not an implementation, just example function calls.

Comment: Results in 'cannot instanitiate abstract class' error.

Comment: @AntonTugolukov Note: `This is not an implementation, just example function calls` :)