# Need help on font.pointSize and font.pixelSize

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2

This is my development environment.

**Qt version:** 5.9.4
**Windows:** Widows 10
**Linux:** Ubuntu 18.04

I have a requirement of setting the font size to 20.25. QML **font.pixelSize** takes an **integer** value, where as **font.pointSize** accepts **real**. So I decided to use **font.pointSize**. But using **font.pointSize** is showing some strange behavior.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Column {
        spacing: 20
        Rectangle {
            height: 100
            width: 200
            Text {
                text: "Sample Text with font.pixelSize = 20"
                font {
                    pixelSize: 20
                }
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            height: 100
            width: 200
            Text {
                text: "Sample Text with font.pointSize = 20"
                font {
                    pointSize: 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With above code I am getting following output. 
For me pixelSize is appearing correct according the value set. But pointSize is appearing very big.
**on windows:**
[image]

**on Linux:** 
[image]

**Note:** in the above example, I intentionally used pointSize and pixelSize both to 20 to demonstrate the difference for same value. My requirement is anyway to use font size as 20.25.

Please let me know, if I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: 20pt is roughly 7 millimeters. That being the case I don't see anything wrong with the images shown.

Comment: Are you using the same font? Download a font and add it to application like so QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont, QGuiApplication::setFont(QFont(QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).first()));

Comment: It would be strange if pixel size will be float -) As for the images -   I see that letter spacing is completely different. You don't change a default values, I guess it is not guaranteed that the default values will be identical. Force to set the same values, at least `font.letterSpacing` and then compare the result.

Comment: You don't say what units your required 20.25 size is meant to be in. Pixels are always with respect to the physical screen geometry (a higher resolution screen will produce smaller text), whereas points are an attempt make the text a consistent size, regardless of resolution (as G.M. alluded to). But that requires Qt to know the dpi of your screen, which it can't always know. So the two sizes will most always be different. I would guess that your 22.25 is meant to be in points, as that is meant to be machine independent, but you need to verify which it should be.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your replies.
@Mark: Sorry that I missed mentioning the unit. It is 20.25 pixel ("font-size: 20.25px;" this is exactly what it appears in the CSS presentation from the UX designer). My understanding on pixel and point was bit wrong. I just found the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141354/convert-pixel-size-to-point-size-for-fonts-on-multiple-platforms

Correct me if wrong, but 20.25px as font size basically doesn't make any sense and font size in pixel should be a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, with a mixture of regular and high DPI displays, you should be using pointSize over pixelSize wherever possible. However, this requires that Qt actually has determine the DPI correctly. Unfortunately, it can get this wrong and yield the observations you make.

In such cases, you can override default behavior by changing it via the command line, e.g.

-platform windows:dpiawareness=0,1,2

Or via setting QT_SCALE_FACTOR environment variable prior to running your application.

For more information consult: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html